# How to delete all the directories with a work in their names in HDFS? (using the command line)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to delete all the directories in the HDFS with an specific word in their names. It has to be considered the directories are in different locations under a common directory. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r /user/myUser/*toFind*
```

The answer to the previous was:

> rm: `/user/myUser/*toFind*': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

It is ok for me to do with this command , and my cluster is cdh5.6.0 with apache 2.6.0
Are you sure is there any file or directory's name contains "toFind" ??
Besides it cannot recursion direcotry .

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it exists, but the problem is the directory could be in a deeper level of the directory path, so the search should be recursively.

Comment: But it seems does not support recursively search like this . I usually use `hadoop fs -R /user/myUser/ | grep toFind `, and then you can use shell to do it . For example , you can use shell pip to do , like `hadoop fs -R /user/myUser/ | grep toFind | awk -F " " '{print $NF}' | while read line ; do hadoop fs -rm -r $line ; done   `